# javascript's equivalent of java's Map.getKey()

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I have a map or say an associative array kind of structure in JavaScript:

```
var myMap = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3};
```

To get keys corresponding to a given value I have to iterate through the map:

```
function map_test(value) {
  var myMap = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3};   
  for (key in myMap) {
    if (myMap[key] == value) {
       alert(key);
       break;
    }
  }
}
```

Is there some function like Java's `Map.getKey()` 
or a better way of getting keys?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting JSON Key from Value or Inverting JSON Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970175/getting-json-key-from-value-or-inverting-json-data)

Comment: if you already have passed the key, then you can directly check if myMap[key] is equal to value or not

Comment: There is no such function in Javascript. You have to loop

Comment: minor correction, it's not an associative array. it's an object literal (although it does act like an associative array, not work like and array though)

Comment: @Diode there is such a function in JS to look for the existence of a key. that would be answered by the guy below.

Comment: @Joseph There is no equivalent of 'Map.getKey' in Javascript. In Java 'Map.getKey' takes the value and returns key. In Javascript we can do this only by using a loop.

Comment: that can be checked using myMap[key]==null

Comment: @Diode oops, my bad. i thought the OP was checking if the key exists and return the key.

Comment: @Joseph The code snippet you have mentioned above is the shortest to serve the problem, if at all you are clear with what actually your question is. I think you want to know the key for a specific value and that has to be done using a loop only. There is no direct function, though a function can be made, still it'll be no point if your usage is very limited

Comment: thnx @TejasvaDhyani, Diode, Joseph. i will use loop, as theres no direct function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var myMap = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3};
```

declare it as a global variable

```
function getKey(value){
    var flag=false;
    var keyVal;
    for (key in myMap){
         if (myMap[key] == value){
             flag=true;
             keyVal=key;
             break;
         }
    }
    if(flag){
         return keyVal;
    }
    else{
         return false;
    }
}
```

I dont think you need any function to get the value of a specific key.

You just have to write

```
var value = myMap[key];
```

Comment: yes, i was going to use a similar function. but i just wanted to know if some function exists for getting key, instead of iterating. thnx

Answer (score 3):

for your specific case there is a faster solution:

```
function map_test(key,value)
{
var myMap = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3};
if(myMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) alert(key);
}
map_test('two',2);
```

In general, there isn't a direct method getKeys()

Comment: what's the point of passing key and value both inside the function?

Comment: @TejasvaDhyani I have just respected original function declaration

Comment: @TejasvaDhyani, i want to use function for getting both keys and values. i will add a mode. which will tell how to use the function. whether to return key or value will be decided by mode.

Comment: @chumkiu. i will pass key or value one at a time. so the solution wont help. thnx for response though

Answer (score 0):

You don't need such function, just write `myMap[key]`, that's it.

Comment: myMap[key] will return value corresponding to key. i want key corresponding to a given value.

Comment: Oh I didn't read your question goog enogh. So you need to extend Object

    Object.prototype.getKey = function (val) {
        for(var k in this) {
            if(this[k] === val) return k;
    }
    return '';
    };
    var myMap = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3};

 alert(myMap.getKey(2));

Answer (score 0):

about several months ago I wrote a wrapper to the native key value storage very similar to Java Map. Maybe it will be usefull to you, but remember getKey uses linear search because this is not a HashMap.

You can check the description and code of the class on my blog (cause it is a long code of only sugar methods): http://stamat.wordpress.com/javascript-map-class/