# javascript myMap[key] returns undefined

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Using an AJAX request I got the following:

```
{"Standardtest":true,"Applikation":"example","Stichwort":"test","Aktiv":true,"Version":"test","AutotestID":"test","Testbereich":"test","Aufwand":"test"}
```

```
var mymap = resultOfAjax;
alert(resultOfAjax);
```

Shows the AJAX result correctly.

but

```
alert(mymap["Stichwort"])
```

or

```
 alert(mymap["Standardtest"])
```

returns `undefined`.

What’s wrong here?

I followed [javascript's equivalent of java's Map.getKey()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495517/javascripts-equivalent-of-javas-map-getkey) but it doesn´t help at all ...

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/q90y7ovb/ If you do console.log(mymap); what appears in the console?

Comment: "alert(resultOfAjax);" this will display the result in your question right? I think this is the problem, if your result is an object, alert(resultOfAjax); will display [Object] kind of things. So I think for your ajax result, instead of returning json response, it returns a string response.

Comment: console.log returns: "{"Standardtest":true,"Applikation":"example","Stichwort":"test","Aktiv":true,"Version":"test","AutotestID":"test","Testbereich":"test","Aufwand":"test"}"

Comment: `mymap` is a string, `JSON.parse` it first.

Comment: Thanks a lot. JSON.parse works.