# AngularJS $http and filters

Tags: json, angularjs, ajax, angular-filters

I have a JSON file, which contains:

```
{
  "/default.aspx": "headerBg",
  "/about.aspx": "aboutBg",
  "/contact.aspx": "contactBg",
  "/registration.aspx": "regBg",
  "/clients.aspx": "clientsBg",
  "/onlinesessions.aspx": "bg-white-box",
  "/ondemamdsessions.aspx": "bg-grey"
}
```

Now I am reading this json file using $http, but I want to add a filter in below fashion:

Using window.location.pathname, I am reading path of the current page, suppose the current page is /about.aspx

Then I want to add a filter in $http response by which I want to read only aboutBg.

The code I wrote can retrieve all the values, but unable to filter that. Please help.

Comment: You mean you need to read only a part of the above json depending on the page you are in?

Comment: yes, you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User this function where you receive the response.

```
function getPageBgClass(currentPage, responseData) {

    if (responseData.hasOwnProperty(currentPage))
       return responseData[currentPage]
    else
       return "none"
}
```

Here is how it should be used in your promise `then` function

```
function(response) {

     var bg = getPageBgClass(window.location.pathname, response.data);

     //Your code here ...
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. You should expand your knowledge about JS Objects and their usage. 

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Answer (score -1):

1. there is no direct method to get key using value from json.
2. you should make sure that there are no 2 keys having same value for below code to work

> ```
> function swapJsonKeyValues(input) {
>     var one, output = {};
>     for (one in input) {
>         if (input.hasOwnProperty(one)) {
>             output[input[one]] = one;
>         }
>     }
>     return output;
> }
> var originaJSON = {
>   "/default.aspx": "headerBg",
>   "/about.aspx": "aboutBg",
>   "/contact.aspx": "contactBg",
>   "/registration.aspx": "regBg",
>   "/clients.aspx": "clientsBg",
>   "/onlinesessions.aspx": "bg-white-box",
>   "/ondemamdsessions.aspx": "bg-grey"
> }
> var invertedJSON = swapJsonKeyValues(originaJSON);
> var samplepathname = "aboutBg";
> var page = invertedJSON[samplepathname];
> ```

[function swapJsonKeyValues from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1970193/1006780 ]

Comment: thanks @Dhairya Vora, Charlie's answer worked for me.

Comment: Why -ve rating for the above answer?